# missing content within result of hook_views_pre_render

Tags: views, search

Am trying to alter fields output programmatically. Most of the posts state that they achieve this by updating content of result array.

But in my case there is no content except entity-id with some views properties!

My goal is to add classes depending on fields values!! Any idea how to do this ?

Here is the output of my **hook_views_pre_render** implementation:

```
db_table (String, 10 characters ) views_view
base_table (String, 27 characters ) search_api_index_solr_index
base_field (String, 13 characters ) search_api_id
name (String, 10 characters ) solrsearch
vid (String, 1 characters ) 1
description (String, 0 characters )
tag (String, 7 characters ) default
human_name (String, 11 characters ) Solr Search
core (String, 1 characters ) 7
api_version (NULL)
disabled (NULL)
editing (Boolean) FALSE
args (Array, 0 elements)
use_ajax (Boolean) FALSE

result (Array, 9 elements)
    0 (Object) stdClass
        entity (Integer) 15
        _entity_properties (Array, 3 elements)
            search_api_relevance (Float) 1
            search_api_excerpt (String, 0 characters )
            search_api_id (String, 2 characters ) 15
    1 (Object) stdClass
    2 (Object) stdClass
    3 (Object) stdClass
    4 (Object) stdClass
    5 (Object) stdClass
    6 (Object) stdClass
    7 (Object) stdClass
    8 (Object) stdClass

current_page (NULL)
items_per_page (NULL)
```

Thanks!! Much appreciated.